# Joint distribution of linear combinations of multivariate normal vectors

Tags: self-study, multivariate-analysis, joint-distribution

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $ \mathbf x \sim N_3(\mathbf \mu, \mathbf \Sigma) $ with $ \mathbf
> \mu^T = \gamma(1,1,1) $ and $ \mathbf \Sigma = \sigma^2
> \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \rho & \rho\\ \rho & 1 & \rho\\ \rho & \rho & 1
> \end{bmatrix} $.
>
> Find the joint distribution of $ \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf 1_{3}^{T}
> \mathbf x & \mathbf C \mathbf x \end{bmatrix} $ where $ \mathbf C $ is
>   a $ 2 \times 3 $ matrix such that $ \mathbf C \mathbf 1 = \mathbf 0 $.

**My effort so far**

We begin by calculating $ \mathbf I_{3}^{T} \mathbf x $
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{bmatrix} = x_1+x_2+x_3 = \sum_{i=1}^{3} x_i 
\end{align*}
which we can see has the distribution $ N(3 \gamma, \sigma^2(3+ 6 \rho) $.

We calculate $ \mathbf C \mathbf x $ and get
\begin{align*}
\mathbf C \mathbf x = \begin{bmatrix}
c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13}\\
c_{21} & c_{22} & c_{23}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
c_{11} x_1 + c_{12} x_2 + c_{13} x_3\\
c_{21} x_1 + c_{22} x_2 + c_{23} x_3
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}
As we have $ \mathbf C \mathbf 1 = \mathbf 0 $, and $\mu_i = \gamma$, $i=1,2,3$, each row of $ \mathbf C \mathbf x $ will have an expected value that sums to zero.

I am however unsure on how to continue from here, how do I go about calculating the covariance matrix for $\mathbf{Cx}$? And how do I combine the two together to arrive at the answer?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag.

Comment: Do not separate the two components:$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf 1_{3}^{T}
\mathbf x\\ \mathbf C \mathbf x \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf 1_{3}^{T}
\\ \mathbf C \end{bmatrix}\mathbf x $$is a linear transform of a Gaussian vector.

Comment: Okay, that is a good suggestion. I let $\mathbf{A} := \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{1}_3^T\\ \mathbf{C}\end{bmatrix}$ and get the joint as being $N(\mathbf{0}_3, \mathbf{A}\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{A}^T)$. Is this a sufficient answer? By evaluating the expression for the covariance matrix I get multiple 0 elements, but others are very unwieldy.

Comment: Yes this is correct.